# How to create html elements using js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have html code which generates ads,And I am trying to generates these with help of js,I am generating last ad only.How can we get the all the ads in the division

Html code is:

```
<div class="list-group col-md-3" id="adsid">

        </div>
```

And JS code is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    var adid = s[i]['id']["0"];

    var desc1 = s[i]['desc']["0"];
    var desc2 = s[i]['desc2']["0"];
    var url = s[i]['url']["0"];
    $('#heading').html(s[i]['hea']["0"]);
    $('#desc1').html(s[i]['desc']["0"]);
    $('#desc2').html(s[i]['desc2']["0"]);
    $('#desturl').html(s[i]['url']["0"]);

    function create(htmlStr) {
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            temp = document.createElement('div');
        temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
        while (temp.firstChild) {
            frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
        }
        return frag;
    }
    var fragment = create('<h4 class="list-group-item-heading"id="heading" name="heading"><font color="blue"></font></h4><p class="list-group-item-text"id="desc1" name="desc1"></p><p class="list-group-item-text"id="desc2" name="desc2"></p><p class="list-group-item-text" id="desturl" name="desturl"><font color="green"></font></p>');
    document.getElementById("adsid").appendChild(fragment);

}
```

And the ads are dynamic,it may vary based on the selection so it should be dynamic in nature.

As I am trying the above code I am getting only the last ad but not all .please help me out in this problem.
And the sample output should be like this:

[image]

Comment: do you prefer vanilla-js or jquery answer?

Comment: provide the solution in jquery

Comment: how is `s` being populated?

Comment: s is the json array ,which is used to get the values from other php file.I think is "s" is not the problem . I am getting all the values but I am unable to construct ad like a pic that I have provided in my question.And I am only getting the last ad but I want all ads

Comment: using `$( ".list-group" ).each(function( index ) { });` you can get all the `div`

Comment: @Muhaimin Abdul :where to place the above code

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use duplicate IDs. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

remove all the `js` code above and replace it with this

```
$( ".list-group" ).each(function( i ) { 
var adid=s[i]['id']["0"],
    desc1=s[i]['desc']["0"],
    desc2=s[i]['desc2']["0"],
    url=s[i]['url']["0"],
    heading = $('<div id="heading">').html(s[i]['hea']["0"]),
    desc1 = $('<div id="desc1">').html(s[i]['desc']["0"]),
    desc2 = $('<div id="desc2">').html(s[i]['desc2']["0"]),
    desturl = $('<div id="desturl">').html(s[i]['url']["0"]);   
    $(this).append(heading)
       .append(desc1)
       .append(desc2)
       .append(desturl);
});
```

Comment: Now it's displaying the first ad,not all

Comment: Can you please check your code once I am not getting anything !

Comment: single ad is repeated many times..when I am trying the above code.